# Why $(-1 \cdot h) = -1$ when $h$ approaches $0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I'm starting to learn about derivatives. I have an example, but I'm not sure about one point in it. I'm pretty sure it relates to basic limit knowledge:

> Derive $$\frac{x}{x-1}$$

So the derivative would be

$$\lim_{h\to0} \ \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Therefore

$$\lim_{h\to0} \ \frac{\frac{x+h}{x+h-1}-\frac{x}{x-1}}{h}$$

$$\lim_{h\to0} \ \frac{1}{h} \cdot \frac{(x+h)(x-1)-x(x+h-1)}{(x+h-1)(x-1)}$$

$$\lim_{h\to0} \ \frac{1}{h} \cdot \frac{-h}{(x+h-1)(x-1)}$$

And this is the part that I'm not very sure about:

$$\color{red}{\lim_{h\to0}  \frac{-1}{(x+h-1)(x-1)}}$$

$$\frac{-1}{(x-1)^2}$$

---

In the denominator I can see how $h$ is practically $0$, so I can see why $(x+h-1)(x-1) = (x-1)(x-1)$.

But in the numerator, why does $(-1 \cdot h) = -1$ when $h$ approaches $0$? If $h$ is a value very close to $0$, it shouldn't be $1$.

Comment: It cancels with the $\dfrac{1}{h}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You lost track of the leading $\frac 1h$ in the line above the red equation.  It cancels the $h$ in the numerator, as you are guaranteed that $h \neq 0$

Comment: By the way, if $h \not = 0$, how come the denominator is $(x-1)^2$? I had said that "$h$ is practically $0$" but I'm not that convinced anymore.

Comment: The denominator can be made as close to $(x-1)^2$ as you like.  You can do an $\epsilon - \delta$ proof:  no matter how small the $\epsilon \gt 0$, you can find a $\delta \gt 0$ such that $|h| \lt \delta \implies |(x+h-1)(x-1)-(x-1)^2| \lt \epsilon$